# Missing META-INF and WEB-INF when creating Vaadin project with Maven

Tags: maven, vaadin

I created two new Vaadin projects in IntelliJ IDE with Maven artifact `vaadin-archetype-application` using the versions `7.5.7` and `8.9.4`

In both cases I am missing the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` in `src/main/webapp` I only have the `VAADIN` folder there, containing the theme with the .scss files.

Where are the missing folders?
According to the official documentation they should be there:
 https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/getting-started/getting-started-maven.html

This is the maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:14.1.4] found in catalog remote
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application/8.9.4/vaadin-archetype-application-8.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application/8.9.4/vaadin-archetype-application-8.9.4.pom (3.1 kB at 47 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetypes/8.9.4/vaadin-archetypes-8.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetypes/8.9.4/vaadin-archetypes-8.9.4.pom (1.9 kB at 37 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-parent/1.1.0/vaadin-parent-1.1.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-parent/1.1.0/vaadin-parent-1.1.0.pom (8.5 kB at 167 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application/8.9.4/vaadin-archetype-application-8.9.4.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application/8.9.4/vaadin-archetype-application-8.9.4.jar (24 kB at 170 kB/s)
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: vaadin-archetype-application:8.9.4
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.example
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: Vaadin8Test
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.example
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: org/example
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.example
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.example
[INFO] Parameter: themeName, Value: mytheme
[INFO] Parameter: uiName, Value: MyUI
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: Vaadin8Test
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: C:\<some path>\Temp\archetypetmp\Vaadin8Test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.217 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-15T12:25:03+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is simply outdated. You could create those folders yourself, if/when you need them.

Below is my **speculation** why it's outdated

---

Support for a `@WebServlet` annotation was brought with Servlet 3.0. This means that there is no need for a `web.xml` file anymore, if one uses annotation. In the generated example this is exactly what is used:

```java
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
```

Vaadin 8 uses it from the beginning, but Vaadin 7 specs were updated at some point. Thus picture is left from the older versions.

*Not related to your question, but V7 is out of life. And official support for V8 ends in 2022. If you are starting a new project, I would suggest to start with V14, which is a LTS version.*

*Edit*:
 The last branch using servlet 2.4 in Vaadin 7 is [7.4](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/7.4/server/ivy.xml)